# i18n vs qsTr (what is the difference)

Tags: application-development

In this tutorial http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/ you can see i18n.tr was used for the internationalisation of text in the Qml file. Today I checked this tutorial: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-internationalization.html where they use another technique (qsTr).

What is the difference between the two? What makes one better than the other in some situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qsTr()` method uses the standard Qt translations support, which is not using gettext. The `i18n.tr()` method is from the Ubuntu SDK and is a wrapper around `gettext`. Many internationalization features in Ubuntu, and Linux distributions in general, are built around the GNU `gettext` system, and so using it provides the ability to use more tools and integrate better with other parts of the system, while the Qt translations system is specific to Qt.

Comment: I can see this general distinction, but this is not very specific... What will break if I choose to use qsTr?

Comment: They are different tools, and they don't work together. Why are you assuming something breaks?

Comment: What I mean is: what are the advantages of i18n.tr over qsTr that I would not benefit from if I choose qsTr. One advantage of qsTr is that it is "standard" (meaning works in every qt target).